# Project NetCDF file using GDAL or QGis

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, netcdf

Can I **project a NetCDF** file with the help of **GDAL** or **QGis**?
The file info is:

```
gdalinfo c:\tomcat-6.0.36\webapps\ncWMS\layers\RAIN_MM_1hour_ac.nc
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: c:\tomcat-6.0.36\webapps\ncWMS\layers\RAIN_MM_1hour_ac.nc
Size is 772, 668
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (19.980464188539599,49.004338539807151)
Pixel Size = (0.012931622920800,-0.008983060104580)
Metadata:
  lat#long_name=latitude
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lon#long_name=longitude
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.5
  NC_GLOBAL#GDAL=GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10
  NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={Time}
  NETCDF_DIM_Time_DEF={1,6}
  NETCDF_DIM_Time_VALUES=0
  RAIN_MM_1hour_ac#_FillValue=0
  RAIN_MM_1hour_ac#long_name=GDAL Band Number 1
  RAIN_MM_1hour_ac#units=mm
  Time#units=hours since 2014-10-01 00:00:00
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  19.9804642,  49.0043385)
Lower Left  (  19.9804642,  43.0036544)
Upper Right (  29.9636771,  49.0043385)
Lower Right (  29.9636771,  43.0036544)
Center      (  24.9720706,  46.0039965)
Band 1 Block=772x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    _FillValue=0
    long_name=GDAL Band Number 1
    NETCDF_DIM_Time=0
    NETCDF_VARNAME=RAIN_MM_1hour_ac
    units=mm
```

Using `gdalwarp`

```
gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=lonlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs' 
 c:/tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/ncWMS/layers/RAIN_MM_1hour_ac.nc 
 c:/tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/ncWMS/layers/RAIN_MM_1hour_ac_proj.nc
```

results in:

```
ERROR 1: Failed to lookup UOM CODE 0
Warning: The target file has a 'nc' extension, 
which is normally used by the GMT, netCDF drivers,
but the requested output driver is GTiff. Is it really what you want ?
```

I tried to save the file in QGis with the specified projection (EPSG:4326), but the output file is limited to a GeoTiff format.

I want the **output data** to also be in **NetCDF format**, in order to serve it to an *OpenLayers* map through `ncWMS`.

PS: I am not familiar with R or Python yet, so I would like an approach using the above mentioned software.

Comment: I don't see any error for the process, so did the output not work? (the lookup UOM thing probably doesn't matter). Your "RAIN_MM_1hour_ac_proj.nc" is a GeoTIFF, since you didn't specify the output format with "-of NetCDF" (GDAL doesn't care about extensions, but helpfully reminded you). Why are you trying to warp a file that's pretty clearly in Long-Lat to Long-Lat? I don't understand why you have any work to do here (??). You maybe want to gdal_translate with -a_srs argument to fill in the metadata.

Comment: @mdsummer Thank you for the part with the output format, I didn't know that GDAL ignores the extensions. My question derived from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470384/how-to-create-an-wms-from-ncwms-server), which gives me headaches, too. The 404 Error (+ pink tiles) appears only when I pan the map to the west of Africa (not where my data should overlay), so I suppose the problem has something to do with the projection. I thought I'd deal with the projection and then with the _Not found_ error. I'll come back with the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mdsummer pointed out, you need to give it the output driver to use, in your case: **`-of netCDF`**:

`gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=lonlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs' -of netCDF c:/tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/ncWMS/layers/RAIN_MM_1hour_ac.nc c:/tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/ncWMS/layers/RAIN_MM_1hour_ac_proj.nc`

It's also clearer IMO to use `t_srs EPSG:4326` rather than an (incomplete) Proj4 string if you want output in WGS84.